# Computation complexity of modified Euclidean algorithm

Tags: complexity

The computational complexity of the extended Euclidean algorithm is $O(log(b)^2)$ ($b$ being the second integer) as referenced by Wikipedia. How to compute the complexity of the modified extended Euclidean algorithm for basis reduction? I know that complexity is equal to the number of iterations multiplied by the cost of iterations. I can compute the cost of iteration but I am not sure how to deal with the number of iterations? [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a question about mathematics and/or computer science with no immediate relevance to cryptography.